# Split text blocks based on uppercase

Tags: php

I have text blocks where the uppercase text is the summery and followed by the details. The problem is the summery and details are combined and i need to split them. since the title size if different i cant cant use substr.

Below is the original text

```
 OFF PEAK WEEKS ONLYOnce the property situated in rolling
```

and it should be

```
 OFF PEAK WEEKS ONLY 
 Once the property situated in rolling
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why would the text end up together like that the first place?

Comment: The csv file which is generated has the summery and description are together. There is no way to separate it.

Comment: Then fix the generator of the csv file, or ask the developer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rangeBig = range('A', 'Z');
$rangeLittle = range('a', 'z');
for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
    if (in_array($text[$i-1], $rangeBig) && in_array($text[$i], $rangeLittle)) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, $i - 1)."\n".substr($text, $i - 1);
        break;
    }
```

Supposing that the real text begins with an uppercase letter: if the last character is uppercase and the actual lowercase, insert there a new line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the line breaks at the first word. `OF` `F` not at `ONLY`